Three-Finger gesture option doesn't exist in Ubuntu 24.04
Has the three-finger gesture been removed from Ubuntu 24.04 settings? I always used this feature to switch between different workspaces. If it has been removed in 24.04, what workarounds are available for this issue? (I don't want to use an extension).
Mouse and Keyboard options in Gnome Tweaks 46.0 

Are you using X11 or Wayland? The gestures will only work if you are using Wayland or else you have to use an extension to achieve this.

This tutorial was a huge help!
